# How to repeat the elements in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to perform XSLT to generate the excel sheet in XML format.

Input XML

```
     <financials-as-of>10/22/2018</financials-as-of>
  <nobs>
    <nob>
      <label-nob>NOB 71</label-nob>
    </nob>
    <nob>
      <label-nob>NOB 70</label-nob>
    </nob>
  </nobs>
```

Expected output

```
 <Cell ss:MergeDown="0">
          <Data ss:Type="String">NOB 71</Data>
          <NamedCell ss:Name="LABEL_NOB">
          </NamedCell>
        </Cell>
 <Cell ss:MergeDown="0">
          <Data ss:Type="String">NOB 70</Data>
          <NamedCell ss:Name="LABEL_NOB">
          </NamedCell>
        </Cell>
```

XSLT

```
<xslo:template match="d:nob">

            <xsl:for-each select="//ss:Cell[ss:NamedCell/@ss:Name='LABEL_NOB'][1]">
                <!-- Copy the Row element -->
                <xslo:value-of select="d:label-nob"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xslo:template>
```

I have repeat the Cell value for two times if the input xml has two items.

Answer (score -1):

Following XSL worked for me to get the expected XML

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:template>
            <Cells>
                <xsl:for-each select="data/nobs/nob">
                    <Cell MergeDown="0">
                        <Data Type="String">
                            <xsl:value-of select="label-nob" />
                        </Data>
                        <NamedCell Name="LABEL_NOB" />
                    </Cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Cells>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

for the following XML,

```
 <data>
    <financials-as-of>10/22/2018</financials-as-of>
    <nobs>
        <nob>
            <label-nob>NOB 71</label-nob>
        </nob>
        <nob>
            <label-nob>NOB 70</label-nob>
        </nob>
    </nobs>
</data>
```

Hope you got the answer expected 
Thks

Comment: It couldn't have worked fo you as posted, because `xsl:template` must have either a `match` or a `name` attribute.

Comment: I missed one before the tag, it worked for me this way, though the main inside match is more appropriate. Thx

Comment: It is not working for me.. Xml ouput failed..   Should we need two xsl:template?

Comment: `<xsl:template>` should not be nested in `<xsl:template match="/">`, so if that is removed, then it should work.